# SQL Multiple Tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, union

I have 2 sets of 2 corresponding tables (4 tables total). The two sets only correspond in one column. I want the query to search through that one column in both joined tables, and be able to return the value in the selected column, even if that column doesn't exist in the other table.

Currently, my query looks like:

```
select z
FROM A1
INNER JOIN A2 
ON A1.x=A2.x
WHERE A1.x= '25'
UNION
select z
FROM B1
INNER JOIN B2
ON B1.x=B2.x
WHERE B1.x= '25'
```

UNION works as long as I am looking for a column which both (joined) tables A and B have in common. I'd like to be able to get values from columns which only exist in A or in B, but not necessarily both of them.

Thanks in advance.

Edit:
Basically, I want two completely separate queries on separate tables, but in one query, with only one select.

Example:

```
  Table A1
  x | y
  ------
  1 | a
  2 | b

  Table A2
  x | z
  ------
  1 | c
  2 | d

  Table B1
  x | v
  ------
  3 | e
  4 | f

 Table B2
  x | w
  ------
  3 | g
  4 | h
```

So I want look for a column variable (such as v,w,y, or z), with a specified value of x. e.g. select w where x=4 should give me h; select z where x=2 should give me d.

Comment: it appears you only need to add an Union ALL

Comment: Can you add sample input and output please?

Comment: I have added some sample input and output. Thanks for the quick response.

Answer (score 3):

You must have the same number of columns in each select statement when using UNION. You can add constant values for columns that are missing. You must also have the same data type for each column.

```
select Column1, null as Column2
from T1
union
select '', Column2
from T2
```

As per comment by @Adrian, you can of course use `null` as a constant value. Otherwise you need to pick a constant value of the data type that is used for the column.

```
select Column1, null as Column2
from T1
union
select null, Column2
from T2
```

Use the sample data provided in the question:

```
select A1.x, A2.z as 'y'
from A1
  inner join A2 
    on A1.x=A2.x
where A1.x= 4
union
select B1.x, B2.w as 'y'
from B1
  inner join B2
    on B1.x=B2.x
where B1.x= 4
```

Result:

```
x   y
4   h
```

With a 2 instead of a 4

Result:

```
x   y
2   d
```

Comment: Following your own observation on types, you should use `NULL` instead of `''`. It would fail for non char columns.

Comment: @Adrian – You are totally right. You have to use `NULL` **or** pick a constant value for the data type of the column.

Comment: I'm not sure UNION can accomplish what I'm going for here. I've added an explanation to what I meant. Will this code work for what I am trying to do?

Comment: @Alec – I think it can. I don't actually follow your sample but I will add something along the line of what your query looks like that will give you the desired output for your sample data.

Comment: I think this might work, but in my real data I have way too many columns to list them all in a query like this.

Comment: @Alec, Both my answer and Mikael's provide the concept you need. Mikael went that extra mile and tried to accommodate your data structure (which is why I upvoted him now). This all of these should definitively get you started.

Answer (score 2):

It would be something like that:

```
select Column1, ColumnThatOnlyExistsInContextA, null as ColumnThatOnlyExistsInContextB
FROM A1
INNER JOIN A2 
ON A1.ID=A2.ID
WHERE A1.ID= '25'

UNION

select Column1, null, ColumnThatOnlyExistsInContextB
FROM B1
INNER JOIN B2
ON B1.ID=B2.ID
WHERE B1.ID= '25'
```

Comment: I'm not sure UNION can accomplish what I'm going for here. I've added an explanation to what I meant. Will this code work for what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

When using `UNION`, make sure all queries return result sets that have the same number of columns with the same type. If you want to return a column from the second query in a union that the first query doesn't have, you can modify your first query to have a NULL value for that column.

Answer (score 1):

So you basically want to do:

```
select Column1
FROM A1
INNER JOIN A2 
ON A1.ID=A2.ID
WHERE A1.ID= '25'
UNION
select Column2
FROM B1
INNER JOIN B2
ON B1.ID=B2.ID
WHERE B1.ID= '25'
```

right?

If so, your problem is probably just that `Column1` and `Column2` are different types.  So, do something like

```
select cast(Column1 as varchar(255))
```

and

```
select cast(Column2 as varchar(255))
```

Should work!

Comment: Although your point is very relevant, I don't think that's the problem OP is facing

Comment: After his update, I agree with you that this probably isn't what he is looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Well, UNION's only requirement is that the number and type of the fields in each result set being UNIONed must match. So, if B has a Column2 and A doesn't, you can select Column1 from the joined As and Column2 from the joined Bs, and provided A.Column1 and B.Column2 are the same type (you can CAST or CONVERT if necessary) the statement will still work. Maybe I'm not understanding the problem, but I think it's pretty easy to solve.